# How can I dim or turn off the light of the Philips Hue bridge itself?

Tags: philips-hue, bridge

I have a Philips Hue bridge 2.0 in the bedroom.
At night the blue light from the Philips Hue bridge itself is way too bright for a bedroom.

How can I dim or turn off the light of the Philips Hue bridge itself?
Is it possible with settings or do I have to cover it?

Comment: Why Sonos support it and Philips Hue not?

Comment: @Tekk you're not likely to get an answer in the comments section... you'd probably have to [ask a new question](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).  If you decide to do so, please [take the tour](https://iot.stackexchange.com/tour) and check out [how to ask a good question for this site](https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately you have to cover it (black gaffa tape is effective) or position it in a room where this doesn't bother you.

I also find it frustrating that TV's, blu-ray players, power extension 4-ways and even phone chargers these days have these really bright blue LEDs. There just doesn't seem to be any need for them to be extra bright or even present in many cases.

Answer (score 8):

The Philips Hue developers have [confirmed that this is not possible](https://developers.meethue.com/content/bridge-led). Just like most routers, the LED status lights are not togglable by the user; instead, you will either have to put the bridge somewhere where the lights won't matter, or find a way of blocking the light.

On Lifehacks, there are some tips on [how to hide bright status lights](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6050/hiding-or-covering-annoying-led-lights-on-computer-and-accessories) which might be helpful - popular ideas include nail polish, super glue and duct tape to hide the light.

Comment: Nail polish, interesting idea.

Comment: Nail polish was one of my first ideas too, however there is the remote chance that the solvents damage the housing. More interesting to know however would be wether only the manufacturer firmware does not allow toggling the LED - in other words, are the LEDs hardwired or are they controllable. In the latter case a custom firmware *could* do the trick. It is at least documented how to change the firmware on this system.

Comment: "...most routers..." - come on, it's not a switch / router thing, just a proxy. And it would be so simple to do that (like adding PoE suppport). I love my MikroTik access points which are able to switch off all lights by pressing a button on the box. Simple and effective - and saves some (even minimal) power for a greener world :)

Answer (score 7):

While [Aurora's answer](https://iot.stackexchange.com/a/749/54) states that the status LEDs cannot be toggled by the user, it is not completely clear whether only the manufacturer firmware does not support this toggling or if the LEDs are simply hardwired and can thus not be controlled by any firmware at all. If they are connected to GPIO pins of the controller, a custom firmware could enable you to switch them of or even use PWM to dim them down. How to "jailbreak" the system is described [here](https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=66346).

If the LEDs cannot be toggled from the system and are hardwired it is still possible to tweak the hardware. The LEDs in question are D8..D11 on the PCB. Opening the case (and voiding the warranty and all) you could try to trace the connections of these LEDs that will eventually lead to some resistors. Removing those resistors and replacing them with higher values will reduce the current and thus the luminous flux.

If you cannot find the resistors and just want to disable the LEDs you can simply remove them... or block the lightpath inside the housing (covering the LEDs). This way the device will at least keep a pristine look from the outside.

[image: PhilipsHueLEDResistor]
Source: [OpenWRT](https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=66346)

Unfortunately, this is not possible to be done from the available pictures only, you'll have to open it and figure it out (you'll need a meter).

Answer (score 4):

Late to this but I thought I'd add for the less technical who find this post. This might sound silly after the technical hacks. I just made a cover out of card which fit over the bridge (actually I found the card lining of a Mcvities pack of 5 cakes was pretty much already the right size). I lined with paper napkins to make sure no light could get through and cut a slot to allow for the cables. Then just slid it over the bridge.

I used white card - but any colour would work. You could paint the card to match your wall.

If you need to access the button on the bridge - just slide off the cover.

This keeps the bridge in pristine condition so if you ever want to sell it - no problem.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I've done something similar with a router I used to have, where I covered it with a box that a UPS I bought came in. It worked.